# CSS3 animation with clickareas

Tags: animation, css

I make a css3 animation. You can see it here:
http://mikevierwind.nl/test/templates/

The container is slide from right to left in the website with css3 transform and css3 animation. But i have a problem with this. When i open the website on iPad. The clickarea from the html5 video is not animating. When the animate is finish, you can not click on the video player. This problem is on the ipad.

The clickarea from the ipad is nog animating... How can i fix that?

Comment: Tht page makes safari on my iPhone4 crash/quit when it reaches 100%!!